# Replacing items in list, but it is returning same value (Python)

Tags: python

Edited: 
This should be the exact same thing I am doing with my code below, but simplified.
I'm replacing values in a nested list. The first 3 values change correctly, but the last 3 replace with the same value. If I run this simplified code, it outputs correctly.. I can't see how this would be any different than my actual code at the bottom.

```
string = [['A', 'B', 'C'],
         ['A', 'B', 'C'],
         ['A', 'B', 'C'],
         ['D', 'E', 'F'],
         ['D', 'E', 'F'],
         ['D', 'E', 'F']]

string[0][2] = 'X'
string[1][2] = 'Y'
string[2][2] = 'Z'
string[3][2] = 'X'
string[4][2] = 'Y'
string[5][2] = 'Z'

for i in string:
    print(i)
```

> > ['A', 'B', 'X']
> >
> > ['A', 'B', 'Y']
> >
> > ['A', 'B', 'Z']
> >
> > ['D', 'E', **'Z'**]
> >
> > ['D', 'E', **'Z'**]
> >
> > ['D', 'E', 'Z']

Will someone please let me know what is going wrong here? I'm replacing string values within the list below. Everything works fine for the first 5 changes... However my last 5 values are each being replaced by the same value.

```
self.seq_string[67][1] = 'Sequence_Images/40_1.jpg'
self.seq_string[106][2] = 'Sequence_Images/39_6.jpg'
self.seq_string[131][1] = 'Sequence_Images/38_6.jpg'
self.seq_string[175][1] = 'Sequence_Images/37_5.jpg'
self.seq_string[177][2] = 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg'

self.seq_string[87][2] = 'Sequence_Images/40_1.jpg'
self.seq_string[116][2] = 'Sequence_Images/39_6.jpg'
self.seq_string[171][2] = 'Sequence_Images/38_6.jpg'
self.seq_string[180][2] = 'Sequence_Images/37_5.jpg'
self.seq_string[184][2] = 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg'

print(self.seq_string[67])
print(self.seq_string[106])
print(self.seq_string[131])
print(self.seq_string[175])
print(self.seq_string[177])
print('\n')

print(self.seq_string[87])
print(self.seq_string[116])
print(self.seq_string[171])
print(self.seq_string[180])
print(self.seq_string[184])
```

The *first* changed values in this list comes out just fine:

> ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/40_1.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/33_2.jpg','Sequence_Images/9_4.jpg','Sequence_Images/39_6.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/38_6.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/33_2.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/37_5.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/33_2.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/9_4.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg']

...But these ones all replace it with the **same value**. *It's okay that the first items are all the same - I'm only replacing the last value on each*:

> ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/35_5.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg']
>   ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/35_5.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/35_5.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg']
>   ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/35_5.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg'] 
>   ['Sequence_Images/16_3.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/35_5.jpg', 'Sequence_Images/1_2.jpg']

Comment: can you simplify this down a bit? perhaps make the code input/output be something like '1' '2' '3' corresponding to what you're actually getting? That will help people answer your question. Not that this is unreadable, but it's definitely something to consider when writing questions.

Comment: This is very hard to answer because we cannot reproduce the problem. Please try to create a self-contained, reproducible example and [edit] the question. In doing so, you may quite probably find the problem yourself, but otherwise we will be glad to help.

Comment: This is very hard to answer because we cannot reproduce the problem. Please try to create a self-contained, reproducible example and [edit] the question. In doing so, you may quite probably find the problem yourself, but otherwise we will be glad to help.

Comment: You have marked this problem pandas. Are you perhaps working with a data frame?

Comment: I guess that for some reason `self.seq_string[87]`, `self.seq_string[116]`, `self.seq_string[171]`, `self.seq_string[180]`, `self.seq_string[184]` all point to the same list, but you haven't shown the bit of code where they are initialized.

Comment: If you had ran the simplified version that you wrote down, you would have seen that it actually works fine... The problem is in the creation of your sublists, as pointed by @Błotosmętek just above. See my answer down there for a full explanation and how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following on @Błotosmętek's comment, the problem may well be that you only have one list that is being pointed to by many different sublists. With a bit of code to explain this, let's imagine I have the following code (basically same as you have I guess):

```
# I create two sublists to be used when I want the same information
# in two different rows of my global list
l1 = ['A','B','C']
l2 = ['C','D','E']
# I now create a global list using my sublist
l = [l1, l1, l2, l2]
```

Now both `l[0]` and `l[1]` point to the exact same object `l1`. When you access `l[0]` and make some changes, Python is actually using it as a pointer to the physical list `l1` and makes changes there; therefore when you then want to access `l[1]`, you will see the changes that you made on `l[0]`.

That's because Python doesn't like wasting time copying a full massive list into a new variable if it's not necessary. If you want Python to actually copy a list in a new variable rather than create a pointer to the list, you need to explicitly do the copy, using `copy.deepcopy`:

```
import copy
l = [copy.deepcopy(l1),
     copy.deepcopy(l1),
     copy.deepcopy(l2),
     copy.deepcopy(l2)]
```

Now your list `l` contains 4 independent lists, and not 4 pointers to 2 physical lists.

Comment: This all makes sense. I am reworking a stored Pandas dataframe using df.tolist(). If I created them separately originally, would any duplicates then be stored as the same object when they are brought back out of the dataframe?

Comment: @agudmundson I'm not familiar at all with Pandas or `df.tolist()`, but I believe that if you did create them separately in the first place they wouldn't randomly merge when put in storage... But I guess you should just try and see what happens! Really, as long as you don't assign an existing list to a new variable anywhere, you shouldn't have any problems.